# Error while running the predict function in R

Tags: r, gdal

I am currently running a species distribution model in R using the SDM package.
Here is a snippet of the code;

```
lst <-
  list.files (
    path = "All_variables/",
    pattern = '.asc$',
    all.files = TRUE,
    full.names = T
  ) preds <- stack(lst) plot(preds[[2]])
  
  ex <-
    raster::extract (preds, spg) head(ex) v <-
    usdm::vifstep(ex) preds <- usdm::exclude(preds, v) preds
  
  d <-
    sdmData(species ~ .,
            spg,
            predictors = preds,
            bg = list(method = 'gRandom', n = 1000)) d getmethodNames() m <-
    sdm(
      species ~ .,
      d,
      methods = c('glm', 'gam', 'rf', 'gbm'),
      replication = c('sub', 'boot'),
      test.p = 30,
      n = 3,
      parallelSetting = list(ncore = 4, method = 'parallel')
    ) m m
  
  gui(m) p1 <- predict(m, preds, filename = 'pr.img', overwrite = TRUE)
```

However, everytime I run the last line, I get this error;
Error in .updateGDAL(object, v, cell, band, setminmax) :
no longer supported

Can anyone help me?

I have tried googling this error but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: This is **not** a problem with `stats::predict` but rather with  `sdm::predict` . PLease read up on function masking and make sure you know which library you are calling.

Answer (score 0):

I found `.updateGDAL` in the library `raster` as part of `raster::update.R` .

The function `sdm::predict`  includes a call to `raster` .  Most likely you should contact the maintainer of `sdm` (see the Description file) and ask them to change their code to be compatible.

Alternatively, find some other package which will do SDM for you.  There are several at CRAN

Answer (score 0):

I used the writeRaster function and was able to do it.

##predict to a raster object
p1 <- predict(m, preds)

## set the extent and projection of the predicted raster to match the predictors

```
 extent(p1) <- extent(preds)
 projection(p1) <- projection(preds)
```

###write the predicted raster to a file

```
  writeRaster(p1, filename="pr.tif", format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Before you sign off on this answer,  please edit to identify the package within which `writeRaster` exists.